# dependencies gradle android studio

Tags: android, gradle, resolve

good evening, i am starting in android but the projects that I have downloaded to base myself on most of them throw me errors in the grandle does anyone know why I get error in almost all dependencies? already try to "update" them to their latest version in the gradle file, the project download it from git hub.

build. gradle (Proyect)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
    dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle (Module app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bigohealth"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.2'

    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.2'


    //implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    def lifecycle_version = "2.0.0"
    def room_version = "2.2.0-alpha02"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.github.christophesmfvvFet:android_maskable_layout:v1.3.1'
    implementation 'com trrf r.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.6.0'
    implementation 'de. , tk./;cx v/8.c8x8hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'

    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.10'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:25.12.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: I get this error:
Error resolving: com.squareup.retrofit2: converter-gson: 2.6.0
Failed to resolve: com.github.bumptech.glide: glide: 4.9.0
etc

Comment: Can you check, if you are under proxy and your android studio is able to connect to internet?

Go to file>settings>type 'proxy' > in proxy settings there is a check connection button which will test if android studio is able to connect.

Also your build tools are 4.0.1. Hope you should have the latest android studio too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check, if you are under proxy and your android studio is able to connect to internet? Go to file>settings>type 'proxy' > in proxy settings there is a check connection button which will test if android studio is able to connect.
if there is a proxy, then provide the details and check again.
[image]

also make sure you do not have offline mode in your gradle settings turned on. Refer following screenshot:
[image]

Also your build tools are 4.0.1. Hope you should have the latest android studio too..